# How To Fix Android 5.0.2 Recognition issue with Windows 10?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, windows, usb-debugging

I have an issue with Android lollipop (5.0.2) and Windows 10. The Windows 10 computer doesn't recognize the Phone. I tried to install the driver manually, I tried to uses another cable and I tried to edit Windows configurations but nothing seems to work. I can not debug any application and I cant even copy the files from the SD card. Any one have any suggestion . Thank You.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port on the same machine?

Comment: Yes , I tried a different port and with a different port